# Problems using pytest with docker

Tags: docker, pytest

I'm working in a project with a django and postgress mount in two separate docker container.

I want to execute the tests in my local environment (out of docker), but I have some problems, I can't, for example, use django_db mark, because the test is skipped.

I can enter and execute the same test without problem, but I can't find a way to execute it outside without this kind of limitations.

Maybe it's some kind of configuration I'm missing, but I can't find nothing about that, and I know I can do this because I worked in proyects where I didn't face this problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a docker port exposure problem? Try to expose the `django_db` container port to your localhost when running the containers, like this:
`docker run --name django_db -p 127.0.0.1:[container_port]:[local_port]`